# How to prove |$Z^4$|=|Z|=$\aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have
Theorem 1:
The cardinality of the natural numbers is denoted as $ℵ_0$.
That is, |N| = $ℵ_0$. Thus any countably infinite set has cardinality $ℵ_0$.

Theorem 2:
If A and B are both countably infinite, then so is A ×B.

Can I use just these 2 theorems to prove  |$Z^4$|=|Z|=$\aleph_0$?

My proof:
Since Z is countably infinite,
then Z ×Z is countably infinite( Theorem 2), and |Z|=|N|=$ℵ_0$, Thus
|$Z^2$|=$ℵ_0$.( Theorem 1)
Using the same method for proving|$Z^4$|.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Suppose $f_2:S^2\to S$ is a bijection. Now if $2\le n\in\Bbb N$ and if $f_n:S^n\to S$ is a biection then for $x\in S$ and $y\in S^n$ let $f_{n+1}(\{x\}\times y)=f_2(x,f_n(y)). $ Then $ f_{n+1}:S^{n+1}\to S$ is a bijection. So by induction $|S^n|=|S|$ for all $n\in \Bbb N....$ BTW we cannot obtain such an $f_2$ for $every$ infinite $S$ without the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Theorem 1 and 2 to prove the desired result, but they should be proved first. In fact you can prove the desired result directly in the following two steps:

1. Define a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and then there is a natural bijiection from $\mathbb{Z}^4$ to $\mathbb{N}^4$ which follows that $|\mathbb{Z}^4|=|\mathbb{N}^4|$
2. Then define a bijiection from $\mathbb{N}^4$ to $\mathbb{N}$ by applying the bijiection twice from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$ which follows that $|\mathbb{Z}^4|=|\mathbb{N}^4|=|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$.

Comment: How about |Z^{2020}|=|Z|, what's the second step in this case?

Comment: @Scott You can show $|\mathbb{Z}|^n=|\mathbb{Z}|$ by induction on $n$.